# Let $\alpha$ be any cardinal. There are at most $2^{\alpha \cup ||\mathscr{L}||}$ nonisomorphic models for $\mathscr{L}$ of power $\alpha$

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

This is an exercise from Chang & Keisler, specifically, exercise 1.3.1, though I'd also like some information on the (I think) related exercises 1.3.6 and 1.3.8. It's as the title of this question states:

> Let $\alpha$ be any cardinal. There are at most $2^{\alpha \cup ||\mathscr{L}||}$ nonisomorphic models for $\mathscr{L}$ of power $\alpha$

where $||\mathscr{L}||$ denotes the cardinality of the language (which, as usual, is at least $\omega$). I admit that I'm a bit at loss as to how to even begin the proof. I suppose part of the problem is that we're considering here the number of models for a given langauge, instead of for a given theory, so I'm a bit unsure of which ifnormation is relevant for that. In the first part of the exercise, you're asked to prove that the isomorphism relation between two structures is an equivalence relation (a rather trivial proof); so I think this fact should be used in the proof somehow, yet I can't quite see how yet. If anyone could give me a hint, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that every $L$-structure $M$ of size $\kappa$ is isomorphic to an $L$-structure with domain $\kappa$. Indeed, given a bijection $f\colon M\to \kappa$, it's easy to see that $\kappa$ can be made into the domain of an $L$-structure in a unique way so that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Hence the number of distinct $L$-structures up to isomorphism is less than or equal to the number of distinct $L$-structures with domain $\kappa$.

The rest is just a matter of counting how many choices you have to make to describe a structure with domain $\kappa$. Since you only asked for a hint, I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: So, let me see if I understood: since what really matters are structures with domain $\kappa$, what will vary is the interpretation of the predicates, functions, and constants in $\mathscr{L}$, right? Supposing for simplicity that $\mathscr{L}$ only has monadic predicate variables, the number of interpretations to each variable will be cardinality of the power set of $\kappa$, that is $2^\kappa$, multiplied by the number of monadic predicate variables. If the language is countable, that will be at most $2^\kappa$. Is that right?

Comment: That's about right. But it won't be $2^\kappa$ *multiplied* by the number of relation symbols, it will be $2^\kappa$ *to the power of* the number of relation symbols (for each relation symbol, you have $2^\kappa$ many options). If the language has size $\lambda$, this is at most $(2^\kappa)^\lambda = 2^{\kappa\cdot\lambda} = 2^{\text{max}(\kappa,\lambda)}$.

Comment: For $n$-ary relations, we replace $2^{\kappa}$ by $2^{(\kappa^n)} = 2^\kappa$, so nothing changes. And functions and constants can be encoded by relations (unary relations for constants, $n+1$-ary relations for $n$-ary functions picking out their graphs).

Comment: Yes, yes, I've got the operations mixed up, but that's what I had in mind. I'm also glad I was right that we can take the monadic case as the basic one. Also, C&K ask in a further exercise (1.3.8) for conditions under which the number of non-isomorphic models will be exactly $2^\alpha$; I'm not sure I get this. How could it fail to have this many (non-isomorphic) models?

Comment: Well, just because every model of size $\kappa$ is isomorphic to one with domain $\kappa$ doesn't mean that all the models with domain $\kappa$ are distinct up to isomorphism. As a trivial example, if the language is empty, then there is exactly one model of size $\kappa$ for each $\kappa$. As a more interesting example, if the language consists of exactly one unary predicate, there are only countably many countably infinite models up to isomorphism: the set picked out by the predicate could be finite of any size, or cofinite with complement of any size, or it could be infinite and coinfinite.

Comment: If you have further trouble with Exercise 1.3.8, I suggest you ask it as a new question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, do you please correct this? : I can assume $\mathcal{L}$ only contains relational symbols. Let the cardinal of $M$ be $\kappa$. Now I can see the structure like every arbitrary tuple of $M$, say $\bar{a}$,  satisfy a relation or not.

Comment: Now a model is a map of:
 tuples of $M$ $\longmapsto$ which satisfy or do not satisfy relations.
So the number of models is the number of maps, $2^\kappa$. my mistakes? however, I know $\mathcal{L}$ would paly a role in counting  but I don't know how.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou You have one such map for each symbol in $L$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Aha, so if the card($\mathcal{L}$)=$\alpha$, then as you have written above, the total will be at most $(2^\kappa)^\alpha$. Yes, please say about 1.3.8 too. About when instead of at most we have exactly.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou As I suggested to Nagese above, you should ask a new question about 1.3.8, rather than discussing it in the comments to this answer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Yes.Sure.You are right. Thank you so much for the point you said above about the solution.